# How to add rounding to arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I spent some time trying to find a way to do basic operations on each element in an array such as sum, round, etc.

I didn't see a built-in way to do this, so I tried to create my own after finding "[Generic 'sum' And 'mean' Methods For Ruby Arrays](https://dzone.com/articles/generic-sum-and-mean-methods)".

Can someone explain why my `round` method doesn't work?

```
class Array
  def sum
    inject(nil) { |sum, x| sum ? sum + x : x }
  end

  def mean
    sum / size
  end

  def round(p)
    inject(nil) { |x| (x * 10 ^ (p-1)).floor / 10 ^ (p - 1) }
  end   
end

puts [1.1234, 1.45656, 1.546567, 1.4577887].mean
puts [1.1234, 1.45656, 1.546567, 1.4577887].round(6)
```

Comment: The answers are great- any idea why this isnt standard ruby functionality? Is it not in the "ruby style" or something?

Comment: This is not a standard ruby functionality because `Array` is intended to be element-type agnostic. How would you define `[4, 'Hello', nil, User.new(:admin)].sum`?

Comment: I appreciate the greenie but you might consider waiting longer before making a selection (say, at least a couple of hours). Quick selections can discourage other answers and may short-circuit those still preparing answers.

Comment: @mudasobwa, [funny you would say that](https://blog.blockscore.com/new-features-in-ruby-2-4).

Comment: @ndn yeah, I am aware of this change :) I answered the question “why it is not implemented [yet].” In my personal opinion, this fashion to bring more Rails-like magic into Ruby is hazardous. But yes, people seem to want this.

Comment: @mudasobwa, actually I like this as summing is not a numbers only operation. I don't like how they handled the default value though. IMO they should have done a simple `reduce(:+)`.

Comment: @ndn “I like this as summing is not a numbers only operation.”—me too, so what? :) Plain old good `inject(:+)` expresses the intent way better, because, you know, in normal life, I use the buzzword “sum” to address summing numbers, not overloaded “composing.” I do not boast to my wife: “Hey, look, what a delicious soup **I’ve just summed up**.”

Comment: @mudasobwa you probably don't say that you *"**reduce** a **set of products** using **cooking** into **a soup**"* either, but I get what you mean 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the following.

```
class Array
  def sum
    inject(:+)
  end

  def mean
    sum / size.to_f
  end

  def round(p)
    map { |n| n.round(p) }
  end 
end

puts [1.1234, 1.45656, 1.546567, 1.4577887].mean
1.3960789249999999

puts [1.1234, 1.45656, 1.546567, 1.4577887].round(6)
1.1234
1.45656
1.546567
1.457789
```

Note that `sum.to_f` (or `size.to_f`) is needed when the array contains only integers. If `arr.sum = 3` and `arr.size = 2`, `sum / size #=> 1` whereas `sum / size.to_f #=> 1.5`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the *why* part of your question, there are three issues with your implementation:

1. Conceptual: `inject` is used to get a bunch of *things* and combine them into one *thing*. Here you have *things* and want to juxtapose the same number of other *things*. The method to do that is `map`:

   ```
   [1, 2, 3].inject(:+) # => 6
   [-1, 2, -3].map(&:abs) # => [1, 2, 3]
   ```
2. Syntactical: `^` is a [bitwise XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), not power to. To do that, the operator is `**`.
3. Basic math: lets make a sanity check by trying to round the number `1.77` one decimal point:

   > (17.7).floor / 10 = 1.7